# How to stop page elements from movings with browser is resized

Tags: html, css, browser, resize, wrapper

I know a lot of people are having the same difficulties as I am, I've tried to apply their fixes to my code but without luck so far. Hopefully you can help me.

When my browser is set as wide as my screen allows the page elements are all in perfect place. However, once the browser size changes the elements move. Visit my website and see for yourself what I mean - www.shedbecalifornia.com

How can I stop this from happening so that elements stay in place no matter the size of browser/screen?

I have no idea which parts of my code are needed for this - the answers I found all related to different problems and slightly different code. Sorry I can't be more specific, but I guess you'll know what you're looking for.

Thanks so much in advance.

```
Wrappers
******************************************/
.ct-wrapper {    padding:0px 20px;    position:relative;    max-width:1260px;    margin:       0 auto;  }

.outer-wrapper {    background: transparent;    position: relative;  margin: 40px 0;   }

.header-wrapper {
background: #1b1e24;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
width: 72.05%;
float: left;
background:#fff;
padding:25px;
}

#content {   
position: relative;  
width: 100%;  

}

.sidebar-wrapper {
width: 25.15%;
padding: 0;
float: right;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: are you talking about description in the middle specifically?

Comment: just remove .article_list_content {
float: right;
max-width: 520px;
}

Comment: Your website is a responsive one. It is build with CSS media queries.. what you are looking for is a fixed width webpage for that you need to have good knowledge of CSS. If you are not comfortable with CSS you need to approach someone who can work for you.

Comment: so you want the text to always be on the right of the photo and only the photo resizes?

Comment: personally from a users perspective i would want the text to jump below the photo on that small a screen width that way your image and text could remain more visible. you would just set a min-width for the text, like 320px, to make it jump below at a specific width and then use a media query to reset the image back to 100% width

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-S/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the article snippets in the middle?

You could change your CSS widths to percentages like so:

```
.article_list_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 35%;
}

.article_list_content {
    float: right;
    width: 61%;
}
```

This is a quick fix that stops the descriptions wrapping under the images

[image: Window at 978px]

Comment: Noah's solution in the comments to your question is a much easier one than mine!

Answer (score 0):

by default to fix width of elements is a better way and use percents (%) in @media queries, that makes blocks responsive.
small hack for responsive images:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```